# Print table name that is querying from?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I get on the results, the name of table that I'm querying from, for example.

> SELECT Customer, Firstname, Lastname FROM Customer

Is such thing possible? Is there any other way around?

Edit: Not possible hardcoding it.

Comment: You can hardcode it into the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with a xml result or if you have some sort of dynamic thing going and can't hard code a table name, this might work.  (I use the CTE just to get a test table.)

```
WITH Customer as (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('1','Ray','Charles'),
            ('2','Bugs','Bunny'),
            ('3','Rube','Goldberg')
        ) t (Customer, Firstname, Lastname)
) 
select *
from Customer 
for xml auto

<Customer Customer="1" Firstname="Ray" Lastname="Charles" />
<Customer Customer="2" Firstname="Bugs" Lastname="Bunny" />
<Customer Customer="3" Firstname="Rube" Lastname="Goldberg" />
```

If you want just the name of the table.

```
WITH Customer as (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('1','Ray','Charles'),
            ('2','Bugs','Bunny'),
            ('3','Rube','Goldberg')
        ) t (Customer, Firstname, Lastname)
) 
select top 1 null as [x]
from Customer 
for xml auto

<Customer />
```

The table name can be extracted from the xml easily.

```
DECLARE @table varchar(128);
WITH Customer as (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('1','Ray','Charles'),
            ('2','Bugs','Bunny'),
            ('3','Rube','Goldberg')
        ) t (Customer, Firstname, Lastname)
)
SELECT @table =  (
    select top 1 null as [x]
    from Customer 
    for xml auto, type).value('local-name(/*[1])', 'varchar(128)')

PRINT @table

Customer
```

The third customer I list likes this approach. :)

Comment: Good answer... XML allows for some tricks, which would not work normally, where SQL experts tend so say: impossible :-)